# how to write to beginning of file with Stream Writer?

Tags: c#, stream

I want to insert my string to the beginning of the file. But there is no function to append in beginning in stream writer. So how should I do that ?

My code is :

```
string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\test.txt";
StreamReader sreader = new StreamReader(path);
string str = sreader.ReadToEnd();
sreader.Close();

StreamWriter swriter = new StreamWriter(path, false);

swriter.WriteLine("example text");
swriter.WriteLine(str);
swriter.Close();
```

But it doesn't seem optimized. So is there any other way ?

Comment: Writing to the start of the file will overwrite what's there. Consider appending data to the end of the file instead of the start.

Comment: You'd need to read the entire file, store it in a string, then insert your new data to the beginning of that string using `String.Insert`, then rewrite the entire file with the modified string.

Comment: @0_______0 that's like what I have done.

Comment: @Oded I'm afraid of overwriting . so I looking to another way if be!.

Comment: Why do you need to write to the _start_ of the file?

Comment: I don't have to. I thought it will be optimized to read and ... if I could write in the beginning of file.

Comment: As you have seen, that's causing your issues when writing. If this is something like a log file, append to the end.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are almost there:

```
        string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\test.txt";
        string str;
        using (StreamReader sreader = new StreamReader(path)) {
            str = sreader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        File.Delete(path);

        using (StreamWriter swriter = new StreamWriter(path, false))
        {
            str = "example text" + Environment.NewLine + str;
            swriter.Write(str);
        }
```

Comment: +1. Also simple `new StreamWriter(path, true)` fix would work as well.

Comment: Code edit: removed unnecessary `.Close()` calls - the `using` already taking care of it.

Comment: The answer doesn't consider, that the file size can exceed an available region of virtual memory space.

Answer (score 4):

If you do not have to consider other processes writing to the same file and your process have create permissions to the directory, the most efficient way to deal with this would be:

1. create new file with temp name
2. write new text
3. append old text from your file
4. delete file
5. rename temp file

it wont be that cool and fast, but at least you would not have to allocate a huge string in memory for the approach you are using now.

however if you are sure files are going to be small, like less than several megabytes long, your approach is not that bad.

however you could possible simplify your code a bit:

```
public static void InsertText( string path, string newText )
{
    if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        string oldText = File.ReadAllText(path);
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(path, false))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(newText);
            sw.WriteLine(oldText);
        }
    }
    else File.WriteAllText(path,newText);
}
```

and for large files (i.e. > several MB)

```
public static void InsertLarge( string path, string newText )
{
    if(!File.Exists(path))
    {
        File.WriteAllText(path,newText);
        return;
    }

    var pathDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
    var tempPath = Path.Combine(pathDir, Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));
    using (var stream = new FileStream(tempPath, FileMode.Create, 
        FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 4 * 1024 * 1024))
    {
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(newText);
            sw.Flush();
            using (var old = File.OpenRead(path)) old.CopyTo(sw.BaseStream);
        }
    }
    File.Delete(path);
    File.Move(tempPath,path);
}
```

Comment: Why do you need explicitly create backing FileStream?

Comment: SerG, it was some time ago, but I bet because it provided an overload with buffer size.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
    private void WriteToFile(FileInfo pFile, string pData)
    {
        var fileCopy = pFile.CopyTo(Path.GetTempFileName(), true);

        using (var tempFile = new StreamReader(fileCopy.OpenRead()))
        using (var originalFile = new  StreamWriter(File.Open(pFile.FullName, FileMode.Create)))
        {
            originalFile.Write(pData);
            originalFile.Write(tempFile.ReadToEnd());
            originalFile.Flush();
        }

        fileCopy.Delete();
    }
```