# Sort lines in a text file by value

Tags: c#, text, streamwriter

I would like to like the WPF application saves time similar to the one in the rankings. Time and number of attempts is not a problem to list but the problem occurs when I want to sort it in a text file. The user will be able to turn on the leaderboard in a text file as well as when the application is completed, the chart (text file) will open and show the user's time.

```
 private void writeText(string strPath, TimeSpan tsDuration)
    {
        using (StreamWriter str = new StreamWriter(strPath, true))
        {
            str.WriteLine(tsDuration / suma);
            //duration= time of the game
          //suma= number of attempts
        }
    }
readonly string path = @"C:\Users\info\Desktop\žebříček.txt";
TimeSpan duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(mt.ElapsedMilliseconds);//this is from other methods
```

The picture is seen as it is stored now:
[image: this is how it is stored now]

But I would like it to be stored like this, and the other attempts were sorted by the value of time:
[image: future text file]

Each time the application is completed, the user's new time should be sorted by how fast it was.
I will be happy for any advice

Thank you

Comment: What does your question have to do with WPF?
WPF is a GUI building tool.
If you need to display a sorted list in the GUI, then this would be relevant to WPF.
But you need to sort the contents of the text file.
It has nothing to do with the GUI.

Comment: @EldHasp Because of the application creating in WPF, so I wrote it to make it clear

Comment: For the case when your time always sequentially increases, you need to write the next line not to the end, but to the beginning of the file.
To do this, you have to rewrite the file.
Perhaps here you will find the solution you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333892/how-to-write-to-beginning-of-file-with-stream-writer
In the case of random time counts, you will have to completely read the already recorded information, supplement it with a new one, sort it and re-write it.

Comment: @EldHasp The following values ​​are up to the user how fast or slow the application will control

Comment: If you need to view sorted lines in the WPF GUI, then this is solved regardless of how these lines are written in the file.
But to find a solution, we need your code related to the output of these lines in the GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there are much smarter ways of achieving the same result but a very simple way would be to:

- Read the contents of the file
- Assign the contents to a list
- Append your value to the list
- Use linq to order the list accordingly
- Write the list back to the file

**Example:**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

private void WriteText(string strPath, TimeSpan tsDuration)
{
    //Create new list of type 'TimeSpan'
    var list = new List<TimeSpan>();

    //Read the contents of the file and assign to list
    string line;
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(strPath))
    {
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            list.Add(TimeSpan.Parse(line));
        }
    }

    //Add your time value to the list
    list.Add(tsDuration);

    //Order the list in descending order - use OrderBy for ascending
    list.OrderByDescending(i => i);

    //Write contents back to file - note: append = false
    using StreamWriter str = new StreamWriter(strPath, false);
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        str.WriteLine(item);
    }
}

readonly string path = @"C:\Users\info\Desktop\žebříček.txt";
TimeSpan duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(mt.ElapsedMilliseconds);//this is from other methods
```

Comment: thank you for the advice but your code always deletes other times and leaves only the last one

Comment: Sorry about that - I've fixed the example